# How to avoid repeating this line of code?

Tags: c#, list

I want to make something that fills a multidimensional list to certain proportions with default value of `T`.

```
for (int x = 0; x < MapSize [0]; x++) {
    List<List<T>> Map_YZ = new List<List<T>> ();
    Map.Add (Map_YZ);

    for (int y = 0; y < MapSize [1]; y++) {
        List<T> Map_Z = new List<T> ();
        Map_YZ.Add (Map_Z);

        for (int z = 0; z < MapSize [2]; z++) {
            T PlainItem = default(T);
            Map_Z.Add (PlainItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could see you looping through the `MapSize` variable and then using some `if()` statements to determine where you add in the `PlainItem` but realistically that's just from theoretical point of view (I have no way to test it since I dont have a C# compiler handy)

Comment: I'm kinda confused on what you don't want to repeat? Is it the whole thing? Then just create a method.

Comment: Well, `List<List<T>> Map_YZ = new List<List<T>> ();` is the same as `List<T> Map_Z = new List<T> ();` (because `<List<T>>` is just another `T`), so you could handle these two cases with the one template function, requiring `T` to be newable.  The difference is in the last dimension where `T` may not have a `new` (or could you demand that?). I'm not sure how to test whether a type is a `List` specialization.

Comment: What do the map variables stand for? What duplication are you trying to avoid?

Comment: to init a flat List, we can use `Enumerable.Repeat<T>(default(T), MapSize[2]).ToList()` which do the most inner loop. But repeating this is not good idea as it cause to have linked values as i comment on @Maksim post provided below!

Answer (score 1):

You are just fill 3-level `List` with `default` values of `T`, right?

Create a help method `Fill` for one list with predefined value:

```
public static List<T> Fill<T>(Func<T> getValue, int range )
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, range).Select(x =>getValue()).ToList();
}
```

And use it for all 3 levels:

```
Func<List<T>> fillFirstList = () => Fill(() => default(T), MapSize[2]);

Func<List<List<T>>> fillSecondList = () => Fill(fillFirstList, MapSize[1]);

Map.AddRange(Fill(fillSecondList, MapSize[0]));
```

You could write this 3 line as one, but it makes whole code not very readable :)

I have changed my solution, because of comment from S.Serp, first solution was very dangerous.

Comment: NOTE: this way, elements are ref-copy of each other! for example if yo modify the value of Map[0][0][0] it will also modify value of Map[0][1][0] and others..!

Comment: Looks more pretty!

Comment: @S.Serp you are totally right, thank for you comment! I have changed the way, looks no more such pretty, but works better.